# How to increment counter inside a loop using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-core

I want to increment the commentcounter for each record by one whenever "btn-like" is clicked.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PostComments)
            { 
<a id=" @item.Id" href="#" class="btn-sm btn-default btn-like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
<span id="commentcounter_@item.Id">@Model.CommentMetrics.Where(a => a.PostCommentId == item.Id).Sum(a => a.VoteValue)</span>
}
```

While the jQuery code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $('a.btn-like').click(function (e) {
                         e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("btn-success");
            $(e.target.id).text(parseInt($(e.target.id).text()) + 1);
                    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                    $('#commentcounter').text(function (i, oldVal) {
                        return parseInt(oldVal, 10) + 1;
                    })
                     $.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("CommentUp", "Posts")',
data: { id: this.id }
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is this code doing (or not doing) that you think is wrong?

Comment: Currently its not incrementing

Comment: On the UI? On the database? On both? Are you getting errors? Are there browser console messages? Please put some more effort into this question.

Answer (score 0):

You may change like this your code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PostComments)
            { 
<a id=" @item.Id" href="#" class="btn-sm btn-default btn-like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
<span id="commentcounter_@item.Id" class="commentCountClass">@Model.CommentMetrics.Where(a => a.PostCommentId == item.Id).Sum(a => a.VoteValue)</span>
}
```

And here is javascript code when btn clicked then for each record comment count will be increased. And i supposed that each span conating numeric value.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('a.btn-like').click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             //Here what this code will do. If you will click on any "btn-like". then this will increment the commentcounter for each record by one.
             // Here code start for increment counter

             $('.commentCountClass').each(function(){

                     var currentVal = parseint($(this).text());
                     var updatedVal = currentVal + 1;
                     $(this).text(updatedVal );

              });
         });
   });
</script>
```

Left of the code i removed because i dont know what was you are trying to do with that code. You can adjust your code with my code. Thank you.

Comment: could you mention what issue is there. I mentioned that i am supposing that from this each span tag i am expecting integer value. if its not right then this could wouldn't increment:

<span id="commentcounter_@item.Id" class="commentCountClass">@Model.CommentMetrics.Where(a => a.PostCommentId == item.Id).Sum(a => a.VoteValue)</span>

Comment: $('.commentCountClass').each(function(){ }); what is doing here that for each span tag this event using class get the value of each span tag and convert to the integer and then increment the each span value.

Comment: I tried all your options and didnt work, i appreciate if you can help further